# Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android

Buenos dias.

Acabo de finalizar el desarrollo de una app, y la he estado testeando todo el rato en un mismo dispositivo, el Samsung glaxy S6.
En el samung va todo correcto,sin ningun problema...lo he probado en otro motrola y tambien va genial. Cual ha sido mi sorpresa que al cargarlo en un sony xperia v o en un xiaomi note con un par de años, no deja, y sale este error:

```
2.controlbt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt/com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2383)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:683)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:419)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5224)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.internal.InstrumentationDelegate.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationDelegate.java:76)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:419) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5224) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151) 
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.internal.InstrumentationDelegate.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationDelegate.java:76) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:262)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:419) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5224) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151) 
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.internal.InstrumentationDelegate.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationDelegate.java:76) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02005d a=-1 r=0x7f02005d}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2006)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:317)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompa
    07-22 11:05:14.240 18143-18143/com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18143 SIG: 9
```

Os adjunto mi main, que es la actividad que da error:

MAIN:

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

y el manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Seleccion"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.oftecnica2.controlbt"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

que puede ser?

Comment: Que version de android tienen los dispositivos??

Comment: El sony xperia  v una 4.3 y el S6 un 6.0....en el S6 sin problemas y en el otro aparece todo esto....

Comment: @SergioCv agrega por favor tus layout nav_header_main y app_bar_main , saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Si los iconos que estás usando en el menú son vectores entonces el problema puede deberse a que ese tipo de gráficos solo funciona con versiones 21 o superiores, para compatibilidad con versiones anteriores se tienen que agregar las clásicas imágenes en png para las diferentes resoluciones (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi)

Answer (score 1):

Estos son los errores que muestra tu LogCat:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14:
>   Error inflating class ImageView
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02005d a=-1
>   r=0x7f02005d}

Se puede determinar que el problema, es dentro de un layout y tienes una referencia a un `drawable` el cual no es en realidad un `Drawable`, en este tipo de casos el problema no se ve en el layout  principal, el problema seguramente esta dentro del layout que carga tu include, `app_bar_main.xml` o el header del `NavigationView` que es `nav_header_main.xml`

```
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que es por las versiones de las APIS que puede no soportar algunas dependencias, intenta agregar cualquiera de estas dependencias:

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3"
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Ve a tu proyecto en Android Studio y abre el archivo **build.gradle** a nivel de módulo.

Situate en el bloque `dependencies` y revisa que tus librería de soporte y diseño coincidan en la misma versión.

*Por ejemplo...*

El proyecto que ando ejecutando ahora las tiene así:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    // más...
}
```

Obviamente la versión que elijas debe ser acorde a la **versión de compilación** y el **target**.

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<paquete>"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Corre la app y comprueba si eso fue.

Si resulta ser que este fue el problema, puedes evitarlo en el futuro usando una variable en el archivo **build.gradle** a nivel proyecto.

Abreblo y crea un bloque llamado `ext` e incluye una variable llamada `supportLibraryVersion`. Asignale el valor de la librería de soporte:

```
ext {
    // Otras...

    // Dependencias
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.1.1'
}
```

Ahora devuelvete al archivo nivel módulo y haz la referencia a la variable:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

Con esto solo actualizas la variable para que las dependencias estén a la par en cualquier instante.

### Otro factor

Fíjate que la dependencia del elemento `Drawable` del cual te hablan, no sea producida por algún elemento de tu archivo **styles.xml** que solo se use en versiones mayores a 21.

Por ejemplo que dentro del estilo principal no uses:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

En vez del `name="android:colorPrimary"`.

También revisa los layouts para ver si hay un componente que intenta usar atributos que solo son para ciertas versiones de Android.

Lo sabrás si ves que se prenden anotaciones *Lint* de color rojo o amarillo.

Saludos!